# migrating to fusion sql api v1

Tags: sql, api, google-fusion-tables

I am working on migrating the Google Fusion SQL API to V1. 
I have followed the instructions from https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide

My question is how do I know whether the migration has been successfully done or not?

Is there a code returned by Google api which can help me identify the sql api version used?

Comment: What do you mean? You simply use the new API, if it works, your done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also migrating.(Waited till the last minute). Not sure what language you're using.
AFAIK the two api's have different access url's.

OLD: https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=

NEW: https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=